# XPATH selecting the root element

Tags: xml, xpath

Is there a simple way of moving back to the root node within any given context. The XML document I'm working with is extremely large and would require using ../.. about a dozen times!!

Any help is greatly appreciated guys.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm guessing you are in a predicate here? and want to return to look at data higher up the tree for your condition?

You should be able to start with a leading / and then work your way back down
e.g

```
/vehicles/cars/car[@id = /vehicles/featuredVehicle/@id]
```

Comment: Ahh I was under the impression I was stuck in a context!! thanks :)

Answer (score 42):

An XPath expression starting with `/` is always referring to the root element. Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp) for the syntax and some useful sample queries

If you want to select the root element itself, simply use `/<element name>` or `/*`

Answer (score 9):

You can use the ancestor axis. Say you have this document:

```
<a><b><c></c></b></a>
```

Then a/b/c/ancestor::a brings the context to the c node and then back to the a node.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Use "/" as your XPath expression. This will select the root element for you. "//" selects the root and all its descendants.